# how to do css images transition with time period with in definite position

Tags: html, css, division

http://paulrwakefield.com/turnpro/

If you follow the link above, In the second section Images appear one after the other with specific time period and semi-circular position.

Can we achieve the same task by only using CSS classes div tags in HTML  without using JavaScript?

If Yes can you provide me the sample code for that?

Comment: Why would you not want to use Javascript?

Comment: @ThomasByy CSS animation is generally preferred because it can be optimized and GPU-accelerated by the browser.

Comment: "If Yes can you provide me the sample code for that?"..have you read the rules of SO? kindly provide us with YOUR sample codes and the community will attempt to help you..as for your question.... YES it can be achieved with css3 animations...